# how to test server's performance online?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, iis-7, liferay

I have three `Liferay portal` -- `ApacheTomcat 7` running on a `Dedicated server` (RAM : 32 , CPU 8 cores, 3.4 Ghz).

All portals are running on the same `Mysql` instance. 
The problem is the response of the server is incredibly SLOW (1 min to log in -- database encryption for password is `SHA-512` ) , and 30 sec to load a simple page. 
It is the same problem for the three portals ( 3 websites ).
The web-server is `IIS` running on `windows server 2008 R2` .
The question is how to determine why the response is so slow .
Is there  a way to test if it is a traffic or network problem or could it be just performance problem ? 
any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a very broad question; what have you tried? Chrome developer tools and Yahoo's Y-Slow will show you which part specifically is taking time when loading the page from a client. Windows' performance monitors will show you processor load and disk load and memory loads when loading pages. MySQL has a slow-query log you can enable. Is anything else slow on the server? What kind of storage configuration does it have? Is it fast to access by file share or remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

When I'm tracking down performance issues on a web site I usually start with two free tools:

- http://network-tools.com/
- http://www.webpagetest.org/

The Network Tools web site will allow you to run pings and traceroutes to check the connection to the server. It also has other tools to check your website such as a great DNS tool.

The second site, Web Page Test, will test the connection time (First Byte aka Time To First Byte aka TTFB) as well many other metrics including the individual parts of the page. It includes the information available in the profiling tools found in most modern browsers with several advantages. First, its from a server that is external to your network, which may not be the case if you're at work and connected to your datacenter with a dedicated connection. Additionally, Web Page Test offers a PageSpeed Optimization Check, which offers suggestions on improving the speed of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use synthetic test such as http://www.webpagetest.org/ or some of RUM (Real User Monitoring) systems. Synthetic testing is run from single or multiple predefined locations, while RUM stats are generated from load times measured on clients browser. There are few dozens of  RUM systems available online like: http://www.gear5.me (requires only javascript snippet) or http://www.newrelic.com (requires server module).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a capture of the site loading with fiddler and debug that.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/performanceload-testing-stress-testing-using-fiddler/

I would also look at your mysql and databases if you have any long running queries and so on. And try to get rid of that w2k8 server as fast as you can ;)